# Two Asynchronous NSURLRequests using Cocoa Touch

Tags: cocoa-touch

I am using the example shown [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) - listing's 1-5 to request the content of a URL and everything is working perfectly. Now my problem is, while the first request is sent off, I want to request content from a second web page, my problem is, even if I duplicate everything there for a second request and connection, and create another variable for NSMutableData that should hold the second request's data, I am only getting the second requests data filled into *receivedData (i.e. the original first requests NSMutableData)

Its like the moment I add code for a second request, only the second request is executing...

Does anyone know how to modify the code in the linked example so I can issue two separate requests?

Disclaimer: learning objective-C now, my background is C#/VB.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "self" as the delegate for both requests, then you'll be getting callbacks for both of the requests and you are most likely only writing the bytes into a single receivedData object.  What you need to do is either create a new class to act as the delegate and create a new instance of the class for each request, or if you want to continue using "self" as the delegate make sure you take a look at the "connection" parameter passed into the delegate methods.  That will indicate which connection the callback belongs to, allowing you to write the data to the appropriate receivedData object.